# React, Node axios not working but fetch is working

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, fetch-api, mern

In my MERN app, I am trying to use axios like I usually do but I changed my file structure a bit and I think that is affecting my ability to use axios (which is shorter and I prefer it).

Server always ran with `nodemon` on `port 3001`
Client always ran with `npm start` on `port 3000`

File structure (A) that has worked with axios in the past:

```
server
    client
        //react files here
    routes
        index.js
    server.js
```

File structure (B) that is not working with axios but works with fetch (I get the error GET http://localhost:3000/api/data 404 (Not Found))

```
parent
    client
        //React files here
    server
        //node files here
```

My axios code:

```
const res = await axios.get('/api/data')
```

My fetch code:

```
const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3001/api/data')
```

Inside of my React App, axios works perfectly fine with File Structure A but it produces an error when I use axios with File Structure B.

So my questions are:
Why does my axios not work all the time while fetch does? (I think it may have something to do with axios needing to be a child of the server while fetch can be anywhere it wants but I feel that is wrong)
Are there any changes that I can make that may get axios to work with File Structure B?

Comment: it can be a proxy issue. Do you have a proxy set up in your package.json file in react?

Comment: Can you also share what error/s you're getting?

Comment: You need to use the whole URL path in your Axios like this:  const res = await axios.get('http://localhost:3001/api/data')

Comment: @ertemishakk In my package.json, I do use a proxy. I use the same proxy that I have used in all of my projects to date: "proxy": "https://localhost:3001",

Also, if you look closer at the last sentence in the File Structure B section, you will notice that I have shared the error that I am receiving.

Comment: @NazmulHasan Specifying localhost:3001 does work, I thank you for that but I have never had to add the entire path in any of my other projects and that's the odd thing but I suppose this gives me a new thing to google. Perhaps there is a proxy issue. This part of my code is copied from my other projects so the issue is either a react update or a sneaky file that I missed while I was copying the project.

Comment: You're using the wrong port in your axios call. http://localhost:3000/api/data, replace 3000 with 3001

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong port in your axios call.

```
localhost:3000/api/data, replace 3000 with 3001
```

Comment: I have never had to specify the port when I use axios which is what I am asking about.

In the past, I've File Structure A and and axios version "axios": "^0.21.4", (earlier versions of axios have worked as well) and I never had to specify the exact path, I could just type axios.get('/api/route")

With my current error, I am using File Structure B and axios version "axios": "^0.24.0", So either, something changed with axios in the past 3 versions, axios depends on the file structure or there is a line of code that I have missed. I am hoping someone here may know exactly why.